# Enable Proxy in Jenkins for Splunk Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, splunk, jenkins-groovy

I've installed Splunk plugin for Jenkins and I went to Jenkins configuration to update "Splunk for Jenkins Configuration". After saving the changes, I clicked test connection and got "Connection Refused" error.

When I ran CURL for splunk URL with proxy I was able to get the response back and this confirms that Jenkins is trying to hit without proxy.

Is there any place in Jenkins where I can configure the proxy so that Jenkins can pick that up while it is trying to connect to splunk server or is there any other alternative approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are running a latest release of the Splunk Plugin for Jenkins. You can see from this pull request, proxy configuration was integrated on Feb 13.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/splunk-devops-plugin/pull/11

You will then need to configure the JVM with the appropriate proxy settings,

```
JAVA_FLAGS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myproxyport
```